# How to hide sub ul inside li with css

Tags: css

I have a menu with sub menu and I'm trying to hide those sub menus for mobile version of my website but I don't find how to do, I though it was easy but for some reason it doesn't work.

My html:

```
<div id="menumobile">
   <ul class="nav menuprincipalhorizontal">
      <li>
         <a href="">1</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="">11</a></li>
            <li><a href="">12</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">2</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="">21</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">4</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#menumobile
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal
{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: stretch;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal > li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal > li > lu
{
    display: none;
}
```

The fiddle:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ddzh8rc9/

Comment: misspelled `ul` as `lu`? Try to use `media-query` to hide it in the mobile version.

Comment: `#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal > li > lu`<-- what is `lu`?

Comment: change `#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal > li  lu` to  `#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal > li  ul`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote `lu` instead of `ul`.

Replace

```
#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal > li > lu
```

by

```
#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal > li > ul
```

Comment: You made the same mistake :)

Comment: @Esko Haha oops

Answer (score 0):

can you please replace with your current css

```
#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal > li > ul
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    #menumobile
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal
{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: stretch;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal > li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menumobile > .menuprincipalhorizontal > li > ul
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menumobile">
   <ul class="nav menuprincipalhorizontal">
      <li>
         <a href="">1</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="">11</a></li>
            <li><a href="">12</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">2</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="">21</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">4</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```